# prestashop 1.7.x how to display custom success message after user creation

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

On Prestashop 1.7.1 i want to display a custom success message after a user has created a account

The defualt action now after a user signs up is to simply redirect back to the homepage

```
public function checkAccess()
    {
        if ($this->context->customer->isLogged() && !$this->ajax) {
            $this->redirect_after = ($this->authRedirection) ? urlencode    ($this->authRedirection) : 'my-account';
            $this->redirect();
        }

        return parent::checkAccess();
    }
```

i would like to display a notification like bootstrap alert (Success or Danger) after the customer registration

something like this to be displayed as a message after the user sign up and redirect back to the homepage, ( a success message , not a warning as shown below)

```
this->warning = $this->l('Thank you for creating a account.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
$this->displayConfirmation('Thank you for creating a account.');
```

Regards